# Update a column of a table with a column of another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I want to copy all the values from one column `val1` of a table `table1` to one column `val2` of another table `table2`. I tried this command in PostgreSQL:

```
update table2
set val2 = (select val1 from table1)
```

But I got this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

Is there an alternative to do that?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) query should look like this:

```sql
UPDATE table2 t2
SET    val2 = t1.val1
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  t2.table2_id = t1.table2_id
AND    t2.val2 IS DISTINCT FROM t1.val1;  -- optional, see below
```

The way you had it, there was no link between individual rows of the two tables. Every row would be fetched from `table1` for every row in `table2`. This made no sense (in an expensive way) and also triggered the syntax error, because a subquery expression in this place is only allowed to return a single value.

I fixed this by joining the two tables on `table2_id`. Replace that with your actual join condition.

I rewrote the `UPDATE` to join in `table1` (with the `FROM` clause) instead of running correlated subqueries, because that is typically faster.
It also prevents that `table2.val2` is nullified where no matching row is found in `table1`. Instead, *nothing* happens to such rows with this form of the query.

You can add table expressions to the `FROM` list like you would in a plain `SELECT` (tables, subqueries, set-returning functions, ...). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.6)

> ***`from_item`***
>
> A table expression allowing columns from other tables to appear in the `WHERE` condition and update expressions. This uses the same
> syntax as the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT` statement; for example,
> an alias for the table name can be specified. Do not repeat the target
> table as a ***`from_item`*** unless you intend a self-join (in which
> case it must appear with an alias in the ***`from_item`***).

The final `WHERE` clause prevents updates that wouldn't change anything - at almost full cost but no gain (exotic exceptions apply). If both old and new value are guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`, simplify to:

```
AND   t2.val2 <> t1.val1
```

See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Is it correct to state that the `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ...` syntax is PostgreSQL specific? Any ideas on how this could be achieved using ANSI SQL?

Comment: @HeatZync: Correct, it's an extension of the standard by Postgres. Most RDBMS have something similar (if subtly different). Don't know what an ANSI equivalent could look like ...

Answer (score 0):

update table1 set table1_column= table2.column from table2 table2 where table1_id= table2.id

1. do not use alias name for table1.
2. tables are table1, table2