# Update table using result of another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have the following query that works fine

```
SELECT RecordID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Value1) DESC) AS Rank
FROM Table1
```

Also, I have another table(table2) that contains (among others) the fields RecordID and Rank. I would like to update RecordID and Rank in table2 based on result of query above. Is that possible?

Comment: This might Help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition

Comment: Or with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473499/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-a-column-of-another-table-in-postgresql/13473660

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple tables in an `update` in Postgres:

```
update table2
    set rank = t1.rank
    from (SELECT RecordID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Value1) DESC) AS Rank
          FROM Table1
         ) t1
    where table2.RecordId = t1.RecordId;
```

Comment: I believe it needs to be `from (select ...) as t1`, without the "as" I get an error

Comment: @MattGreer . . . Postgres definitely does not require `as` to declare table aliases.  Perhaps you should ask a question for the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me (in `mysql`) was :

```
update table2, (SELECT RecordID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (Value1) DESC) AS Rank 
    FROM Table1) tempTable 
set table2.Rank = tempTable.Rank 
where table2.RecordId = tempTable.RecordId;
```

Comment: Tested in mysql, can be helpful for people searching a solution not necessarily for Postgres.

Comment: But the question is tagged with `postgresql`

Comment: I found this question by searching for a similar issue not specifically for `postgresql`, others may also find it useful.