# INSERTING a single field into a table, referenced from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert a field in a that references an id field in another table.
The id field it is to going is next to the field 'test' (column - codedescription, table typecategory) and coming from an id field next to the word 'assessment' (column categorydescription, table typecategory)

```
INSERT INTO codetype
(typecategoryid)
Where codedescription='test'
SELECT id FROM typecategory WHERE categorydescription='Assessment Types'
```

There are plenty of examples of inserting entire columns but nobody has written how to insert a single field from another table.

table - codetype
id                  bigserial   primary key
codedescription     varchar
typecategoryid      bigint foreign key to typecatogory on the ID column

Table - typecategory
ID                   big serial primary key
categorydescription  varchar

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What happens when you run this script? Are you getting an error, or just not the results you expect?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to create the `typecategoryid` field at the same time you are populating it?

Comment: I am using postgres. There is a column typecategoryid with plenty of info. I need to populate the last three fields with an id field from a different table (typecategory)

Comment: Please post table structures so we can better help you.

Comment: Sorry I added the table structures above.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the column already exists and there are are already records in the rest of the columns in the table, then you need an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`.

Looks like this post might help you: [Update a column of a table with a column of another table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473499/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-a-column-of-another-table-in-postgresql)

maybe

```
UPDATE codetype c
SET    c.typecategoryid = t.id 
FROM   typecategory t
WHERE  c.codedescription = 'test' and t.categorydescription='Assessment Types'
```

Comment: UPDATE codetype
(typecategoryid)
WHERE codedescription='Test'
SET typecategor.id = codetype.typecategoryid
WHERE typecategoryid=4
???

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.